# How can I edit GIS shapefiles in a geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

I have a code in ArcPy which fills some fields in some shapefiles using filed calculator. But this only work when shapefiles are stored in a folder, out of geodatabase. How can I make it work when shapefiles are inside of the geodatabase?

Answer (score -1):

You can run the function:

```
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass() in python 3
```

or

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion() in python 2.7
```

to change the format into ESRI format, and have no problem.

You can look for the function info in [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm)